# Log4j2 add word to every log call

Tags: java, log4j2

So i have a java app that is launched from a central app the problem is that you can lunch many apps in the same time why causes the logs to be almost unreadable and my solution was just to add a app_instance_id to each call for the log but that means to modify way too many classes .

My question is : does log4j has a feature similar to this? or is there a better approach ?

PS: i do not what a separate file for every app instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [MDC](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html).  You can set your app-instance-id in the MDC at bootstrap time.  Any threads that are spawned afterwards will inherit that value.

```
MDC.put("instanceId", instanceId);
```

Then, in your log4j pattern, specify `%X{instanceId}` to add the instanceId to every log line.  This way, the log4j config will be the same for all your instances.

Comment: sounds exactly like what i need... i'm gonna try it out :D thx

Comment: u sir deserve a cookie :D although the instance did not apply to children threads as stated in doc : "A child thread automatically inherits a copy of the mapped diagnostic context of its parent."

Comment: You can change this with system property `isThreadContextMapInheritable`. See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties